# Html tag with runat="server" thrown RegisterForEventValidation can only be called when rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, rendercontrol

in my project in dot.net WebForm I am implementing a dynamic tab menu.
The tab control is managed in the aspx file. When a tab is selected it takes care of loading the corresponding ascx file (UserControl).
Through the RenderControl I was able to load the UserControls.

**Ajax call to handle tab switching**

```
$('a[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var targetId = $(e.target).data('bs-target').substring(1);
    loadUserControl(targetId);
});

function loadUserControl(userControlId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Page.aspx/LoadUserControl",
        data: JSON.stringify({ userControlId: userControlId }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#tabContent').html(response.d);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

**WebMethod to render the UserControl**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string LoadUserControl(string userControlId)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Handler is Page page)
    {
        var userControl = page.LoadControl($"{userControlId}.ascx");
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                userControl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that the moment an html tag like input or aspx:Button has runat="server" as attribute, I get this exception: *RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render*.

Browsing the internet everyone says that the solution to this problem is to disable the EnableEventValidation attribute in the UserControl page and override the VerifyRenderingInServerForm method as follows:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
       server control at run time. */
}
```

I know that the EnableEventValidation attribute is related to security, so I would not want to disable it.
Can you give me some clarification on this? I can't find any other solution to this problem.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks like you're trying to pull a full aspx response (including all of its associated session data, encrypted/hidden values, event structure, etc.) into an *already established* aspx response (the page being viewed).  To my eyes, this looks like it would cause a conflict because you now have two totally separate aspx session states represented in a single page, and posting it back would send unexpected/uninitialized fields to the server.

Comment: Yes indeed the UserControl would have its own lifecycle, such as fetching data from the database to autocomplete fields (this is a profile edit page) and in case of changes, saving the data. How do you recommend I proceed at this point? I've opted for UserControls because they allow me to modularize the code, having many sections to manage on one page, but maybe at this point I'm wondering if it's actually the best solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not super fluent in aspx user controls, but it seems like you'd want to initialize those within the page itself to avoid a lifecycle conflict.

Comment: Obviously if I initialize all UserControls on initial page load everything works fine, but this leads to excessive initial loading, which is why I wanted to load dynamically on menu click. I still can't find a solution :(